# AttributeError: module 'pyrsgis.raster' has no attribute 'createDS'

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I use Produce Training Data For Deep Learning QGIS plugin to produce a .tiff file for training the model.

When I run the Plugin this Error has occurred:

Python error: An error has occurred while executing Python code: See message log (Python Error) for more details.

As shown in Python warning Error:

AttributeError: module 'pyrsgis.raster' has no attribute 'createDS'.

The question is: Should I reinstall the library GDAL from scratch or would it be possible to fix this issue by creating the attribute in the .py file in the folder where the plugin is!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here:
https://pythonissues.com/issues/2193533

The module needs updating by the developer but there is a good temporary fix, here's how:

Go to the location and open dataGeneratorDeepLearning8.py file in any text editor (notepad, notepad++, Python IDLE). --> Make changes as shown in commit 48929c3 --> Save the file and restart QGIS.